# With JQuery how can you make an array of inputs from checkboxes into one variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to make the data from this jquery submit go into one variable that I can put into html.  I am using the append button to add html to my form, but can't figure out how to make the `data` variable into an array of each check box value .

https://jsfiddle.net/soljohnston777/k5yc1y2a/2/

JQuery:

```
$(".checkboxadd").click(function(){
                $('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v){
                  //alert(this.value);
                  if($(v).prop('checked')){
                  var data=$(v).val();
                  $("#div_to_add_this_checkbox_value").append("<input type=hidden name='pnpID_instructions' value=\'"+data+"\' />P&P #'s: "+data+"");}
                });
});//end ajaxifypolicies
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="add_policies_checkbox1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="add_policies_checkbox2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="add_policies_checkbox3"/>
  <button class="checkboxadd">Submit</button>
<div id="div_to_add_this_checkbox_value"></div>
<div> Check mark all 3 then hit submit, What I want is the output like an array:<br>P&P #'s:1,2,3 <br> (and the hidden value="1,2,3")
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a multi select element, and possibly this jquery plugin: http://loudev.com/. Then you can let the user build the list then store the data.

Comment: They won't let me use add-ons with this code, only strictly bootstrap.  Unfortunately

Comment: I thought there would be a way with $.each somehow

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: P&P #'s:1,2,3  (with the value="1,2,3"), basically injecting an array of the Data value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an array to a string you can use `array.join(',')`.

```js
$(".checkboxadd").click(function() {
var data = [];
$('[id^="add_policies_checkbox"]').each(function(i, v) {  
  if ($(v).prop('checked')) {
    data.push($(v).val());
  }
});
console.log(data);

$("#div_to_add_this_checkbox_value").html('P&P #s:' + data.join(',') + "<input type='hidden' name='pnpID_instructions' value='"+data.join(',')+"' />");


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="add_policies_checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="add_policies_checkbox2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="add_policies_checkbox3" />
<button class="checkboxadd">Submit</button>
<div id="div_to_add_this_checkbox_value"></div>
```

Comment: I missed the .join in the documents - Works Great!   :)